# Open JSP page as PDF file

Tags: java, jsp, pdf-generation, itext

In reporting section of my application report is generated and contents are shown on jsp page, as part of requirement user wants to download report in form of both excel and pdf.

I got this thing work for excel by changing contenttype of jsp page as below

```
contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel"
```

However same thing for pdf is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```